# Defined component style not working

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

`margin-top` style is not being applied to the component. I don't quite understand what I'm missing here.

**Home.js**

```
const BannerSd = styled(Banner)`
    margin-top: 15%;
`;

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <BannerSd/>
        <Content/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

**Banner.js**

```
function Banner() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <h3>SubTitle</h3>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Banner;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the `className` down to the Banner component, as described in the [styled-components docs](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-components).

```js
function Banner({className}) {
    return (
        <div className={className}>
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <h3>SubTitle</h3>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Banner;
```

**Edit:** Wrong link